# How does the Waves class in the book Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirecX11 work?

Tags: 3d

I'm confused by the `Waves` class [implementation](https://github.com/utilForever/DirectX/blob/master/DirectX%2011/Frank%20D.%20Luna/Common/Waves.cpp#L55) in the source code of the book *Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirecX11*:

```
float d = damping*dt+2.0f;
float e = (speed*speed)*(dt*dt)/(dx*dx);
mK1     = (damping*dt-2.0f)/ d;
mK2     = (4.0f-8.0f*e) / d;
mK3     = (2.0f*e) / d;
```

What do the parameters mean? How are the waves generated? I've tried searching waves implementation and found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716887/how-to-render-ocean-wave-using-opengl-in-3d , I looked up the links mentioned by the answer but I couldn't understand the complicated equations and it seems that the equations have no relation with the code above. I also tried searching "spatially damped wave", and then I found https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/223366/wave-equation-with-spatial-damping, that didn't help me, neither...

Comment: Could you be a little more specific as to what you don't really understand? Is it how the waves are generated and the parameters? I'm sure many people here could help you.

Comment: @ArjanSingh Yes! I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This implementation represents the water as a regular height field grid. The function parameters `m` and `n` are the dimensions of the grid, `dx` is the regular distance between the water vertices, `dt` is the time step, `speed` is the speed of the movement and `damping` is a constant to ease disturbance as the water flows from the disturbance center.